# Form to send iOS app via text message

Tags: ios, sms, saas

**Is there a service that allows me to put a form on my site that will send a link to my iOS app to a user?**

1. User goes to my site
2. User inserts their cell phone number in a field
3. User receives a text message with the link to download my app

Does this make sense? Is there a better way? I've seen this before but can't remember where...

Currently do people really just take out their iPhones, open the app store, search for the app name to download it?

PS: Before posting I searched Google and this site but didn't find any answer.

Comment: You want an interaction that works if the user finds your site on some device other than their iPhone?

Comment: To send a SMS you will access to SMS Gateway which cost money.  Just do what @cscott530 mention below.  Put a link to your app in iTunes on your site.  That link will take them directly to it.

Comment: I like QR codes but I would use it as an alternative method to get the app. Not Everyone knows how to use QR codes. I don't want to get into explaining what QR codes are. I just want them to download my iOS app. I don't mind paying a bit of $ to make it work (either for a third party or SMS gateway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you're looking for, but probably a lot easier for you to do: You could create a QR-Code that contains a link to your app in the App Store.  Then people can scan it with their phones (there are tons of popular apps that can do this), and when it opens the URL, the user will be redirected to the app store.

Just use the `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/[...]` link from iTunesConnect for your app.

Comment: The problem with the URL is that it doesn't download the app on the phone. Lots of people I know never connect their phones to iTunes. I'm sure people end up doing the steps I mentioned in my question (search for the app name on the phone's app store). When I downloaded the Oink or Path app I liked that I could just put in my phone number and then just select the link in my text message which opens the app store on my phone. (Oink no longer exists and Path no longer does this so it's hard to find an example)

Comment: When a person scans the QR code with their phone (it doesn't matter if it appears on a computer screen or a piece of paper or what), the scanner will decode the URL in the QR Code. It sees that its an iTunes/App Store link, and will immediately redirect the user to App Store page for your app, which they can download just as if they searched for it.  It's just like if you text someone the link, and they open it and automatically get redirected to the App Store